# Anodization Titanium current vs voltage

Tags: metal

I am fairly new to anodization of Titanium. It concerns anodization using oxalic acid with the sole purpose of coloring Titanium grade 2 parts (= type III?). After some research online, I found a lot of information on the required voltage levels per color. However, to my understanding, the "purpose" of the voltage is only to induce a certain current. I did find a few articles and discussions on other forums about anodization based on the current density, but I mainly found information related to a constant voltage. Considering that the current generated by a certain voltage also depends on the resistance of the anode, cathode, electrolyte, etc., I'm wondering why there is this little information on the required current density instead of the required voltage.

Can anyone give me (a link to) the information that I'm looking for or explain me why my reasoning is not correct?

If any information is missing, please let me know!